# QML Layout.alignment not behaving as expected

Tags: qt, qml

In the QML below, I have three items in a row layout with each item needing to be centered vertically in that layout.

The middle item is a `PlayerSelector`, which creates a varying number of text edit boxes to change the name of each player. I've tried two different ways to keep the `PlayerSelector` vertically centered. The one that works for me causes a runtime warning, the suggested method doesn't keep that item centered vertically. See these screen caps and the code below:

Method 1&2 both center initially
[image: Each method correctly centers the default player set]

Method 1 correctly maintains vertical centering (`anchors.verticalCenter`)
[image: Correct centering using anchors.verticalCenter]

Method 2 does not maintain vertical centering (`Layout.alignment`)
[image: Incorrect centering using Layout.alignment]

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Item {
    id: gameStart
    anchors.top: parent.top
    height: parent.height
    width: parent.width
    signal playGame

    RowLayout {
        id: layout
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

        RoundButton {
            id: playButton
            text: "Play"
            width: 40
            radius: 2
            font.pointSize: 12
            onClicked: {
                var players = selector.playerArray
                for (var i =0; i < players.count; i++) {
                    console.log(players.itemAt(i).playerName)
                    game.addPlayer(players.itemAt(i).playerName)
                }
                gameStart.playGame()

            }
        }

        PlayerSelector {
            id: selector
//            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter             // method 2
            anchors.verticalCenter: layout.verticalCenter  // method 1
        }

        RoundButton {
            id: quitButton
            text: "Quit"
            width: 40
            radius: 2
            font.pointSize: 12
            onClicked: {
                game.quit()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with method 1 is that although it works, it shows this runtime warning:

```
qrc:/qml/GameStart.qml:41:9: QML PlayerSelector: Detected anchors on an item that is managed by a layout. This is undefined behavior; use Layout.alignment instead.
```

Is there a way to get the alignment I'm after but not have the runtime warning?  I'm worried about the `undefined behavior` part.

Comment: How are you specifying the size for `PlayerSelector`?

Comment: Do you think I should add the code for the PlayerSelector?  I was worried the question was already too long.

Comment: The PlayerSelector consists of a RowLayout containing two column layouts.  The first column layout has the Label and ComboBox.  The 2nd column  layout has a repeater of Rectangles containing TextFields.  Ignoring widths of things, the Label is fixed height 32, the ComboBox is given no height.  In the 2nd column, the Rectangles have height of 32 and the TextField has a font.pointSize 12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alignment only works when the Layout size is bigger than the item size. So for example if layout's `height` is 200 and item's `height` is 100, then when you align vertically, the item will have 50 pixels on either side. But if the item is also 200 pixels, then it just fills it. In your case the `PlayerSelector` has the same `height` as the `RowLayout`, and is therefore aligned. The other items are not aligned in this case.

IMO there are two approaches in sizing a layout and its children:

1- Explicit sizes go from parents to children: you explicitly specify the size for the layout, and the size of children is relative to the size of layout. This is my personal preference since it is easier to make sure everything is sized and aligned correctly. When screen is resized things just shrink or stretch proportionately. In this approach only use `Layout` attached properties for both size and alignment.

2- Size of layout is implicitly defined from the size of the child items. (your approach) This approach can be more flexible and give you non-stretched but functional layouts when screen size changes, but there are more degrees of freedom for things to go wrong when screen is resized. In this approach, you can use (preferably) implicit or explicit sizes for children, but alignment still should be handled by `Layout` attached properties.

In your case it seems that the layout's `height` is set to the `height` of `PlayerSelector` (the largest `height`), so the other items are at the top of their row placement, and `PlayerSelector` is actually the only item that is vertically centered (it fills the whole `height`). So you could set alignment for all other items as well to make sure everything is centered.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  It clarifies some things I didn't fully understand.  I also feel #1 is a better approach.  When I set the height and width properties of the RowLayout to be parent.height and parent.width, though, shouldn't the problem go away?  It behaves the same way for me.  In this situation the children are definitely smaller in size than the layout.

Comment: It looks like I have some issues in PlayerSelector that need to be sorted out regarding layout sizes.  I'll mark your answer as correct.

Comment: It's not easy to tell from screencaps, but the PlayerSelector item is moving down rather than the Play and Quit buttons moving up.  Telling those buttons to also use Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignVCenter does not change anything.

Comment: I solved my problem by reworking PlayerSelector to have as its root item a layout object - i.e. one with implicitHeight and implicitWidth.  Prior to that the PlayerSelector (id: selector) always had an implicitHeight of 0 and the surrounding Layout wouldn't make any adjustments for the alignment.